# Could not load type 'MyProject.MvcApplication'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm not sure what's happen, but now i've just upload a new dlls for my mvc website and i'm getting the following error

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyProject.MvcApplication'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyProject.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

I've have rebuilt the application locally and and works. So the issue is just on the remote server. I have uploaded all DLLs

Comment: How did you upload the dlls? FTP? If so did you use ASCII mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UpTheCreek, is kinda spot on questioning the ftp. My connection is getting throttled in my hotel wifi. As previous mentioned on stackoverflow the message isn't descriptive of the issue. So i went to work and ftp'd the whole bin and it worked.  Very frustrating.